# Elevating privileges in SharePoint(Difference between Farm & Sandboxed solutions)

Tags: sharepoint

I am learning difference between Farm & Sandboxed solutions. Following difference is not clear to me. Explaining with examples will be appreciated and also will be helpful for the community.

**Farm Solution:** 
Ability to elevate privileges.

**Sandboxed solution:**
Can't elevate privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandboxes solutions cannot elevate on purpose.  It's a security precaution to not affect stability of the farm.  See this [book excerpt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff872402%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more details.